# AngularJS: Input "required" attribute deletes its ng-model entirely when the control is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've noticed something odd in AngularJS 1.7.9.

If I use the code `<input type="text" ng-model="object.property">`, and empty the control (*i.e.*, set its value to an empty string), then `object.property` also gets set to an empty string – which is what I want and expect.

However, if I add the `required` attribute to the `<input>`, and empty the control, then `property` gets removed from `object` entirely!

Is this intended behavior? If so, is there a workaround?

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('requiredTestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'delete this text'
    };
    
    $scope.userWithRequiredName = {
        name: 'delete this text'
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="requiredTestController">

    <p>user: {{ user }}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    
    <hr>
    
    <p>userWithRequiredName: {{ userWithRequiredName }}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userWithRequiredName.name" required>

</body>
```

Comment: It seems that this *is* intended behavior:

"The default behaviour in ngModel is that the model value is set to undefined when the validation determines that the value is invalid."

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

That seems very weird to me – I'd expect it to set the property to null instead.

Answer (score 1):

By default invalid values are not stored into model (null is saved instead), and empty string is not valid in your case, to change this add:

```
ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}
```

Comment: It's *not* saving null into the model, though. It's removing the property entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"`:

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-model-options Directive API Reference — Model updates and validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#model-updates-and-validation)

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('requiredTestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'delete this text'
    };
    
    $scope.userWithRequiredName = {
        name: 'delete this text'
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="requiredTestController">

    <p>user: {{ user }}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    
    <hr>
    
    <p>userWithRequiredName: {{ userWithRequiredName }}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="userWithRequiredName.name"
           ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" required>

</body>
```